# Understanding Kirchhoff's first law in charged conductors

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, conductors, approximations

I wonder about Kirchhoff's first law in charged conductors. Consider:

$$j = \sigma E \implies \nabla \cdot j = \sigma (\nabla \cdot E) = \frac{\sigma \rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

This means that Kirchhoff's first law does not hold true if the conductor is charged ($\rho \neq 0)$

But is not that exactly the case with any conductor connected to a capacity?

Are the surface charges not exactly that excess in charge that create the electric field.

See [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102536/).

Comment: Conductors in usual low frequency circuits have $\rho = 0$ inside, non-zero charge density can be only on their surface. But on the surface, the local Ohm law $\mathbf j = \sigma \mathbf E$ does not hold, because current component perpendicular to the surface can be zero, while electric field is not, so the two vectors are not parallel. Also, $\sigma$ is not position independent on the surface. One can have non-zero charge density on the surface while divergence of $\mathbf j$ is zero, this is e.g. when the surface charge is constant in time.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, Kirchhoff's circuit laws only apply when the [lumped circuit approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped-element_model) is valid and one of the assumptions of the lumped circuit approximation is that no charge accumulates in the conductors connecting the circuit elements.

However, in case there is significant charge accumulation in the conductors, circuit theory can easily account for this by modeling *parasitic capacitor(s)* at the appropriate points in the circuit.

> But is not that exactly the case with any conductor connected to a capacity?

Usually the charge accumulates significantly only on the "plates" of the capacitors. These are considered part of the capacitor element and not part of the interconnect wiring, so charge accumulation here presents no special issue in terms of using KCL to solve a circuit. The charge that accumulates on the capacitor plate is simply accounted for as a current in or out of the capacitor element.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to state KCL without stipulations regarding charge accumulation. Rewrite the continuity equation (or take the divergence of Ampere's law) to get
$$\mathbf\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf j + \frac{\partial \mathbf D}{\partial t}\right)=0.$$
$\partial \mathbf D/\partial t$ is the so-called [displacement current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current) density. If we take $\mathbf j +\partial \mathbf D/\partial t$ to be "the current density", thus including the displacement current in what we call "current", then the total current leaving any closed surface is always zero.

Most famously, when current is flowing into one plate of a capacitor and out the other plate, displacement current is present between the plates of the capacitor. Taking this into account partially justifies that language of "[current flowing through a capacitor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppWBwZS4e7A)". On the other hand, displacement current can be considered negligible in conductors (and zero at steady-state), so there is no real ambiguity in which version of current we speak of in practice.

Comment: Reference for stating KCL this way? It does not seem viable for circuits, as displacement current is not limited to conductor body and also because KCL would refer to additional unknown variables not appearing in KVL, not just $I$ which appears in KVL.

Comment: This is the correct answer. When you use KCL, you are implicitly promising to account for displacement current. And when you use KVL, you are implicitly promising to account for induction.

Comment: @JánLalinský The "extra unknown variables" come from the geometry. You can't understand the relation between charge and potential without them. If you do IC design, one of the last steps is to take the physical layout, extract a circuit model from the geometry, and simulate that to gain confidence in the design. The extracted circuit has a *lot* of tiny capacitors in it to address this problem.

Comment: @JánLalinský    R. S. Eisenberg, "Kirchhoff's Law Can Be Exact," arXiv preprint [arXiv:1905.13574](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.13574), 2019.

I agree that the subtlety of displacement currents is lost if you are just given a lumped circuit. It's still useful to keep them in the back of one's mind when converting a real circuit into an approximate lumped circuit for instance, where important paths of displacement current flow can be modeled by adding parasitic capacitors. $I$ doesn't appear explicitly in KVL except via Ohm's law etc. where the displacement current doesn't really matter anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I meant $I$ due to resistors, and $\dot{I}$ due to inductors, and $\int I dt$ due to capacitors; the fact KCL refers to $I$ only allows us to solve the circuital equations in these simple linear cases. When one introduces fictitious "parasitic" network elements, the same KCL with conduction current is still used in the resulting network. So I don't see how KCL with displacement current helps - one can introduce as many parasitic elements as needed to get a model to fit anything. Are you saying one can justify this fitting enterprise or limit its complexity using laws $\mathbf D$ obeys?

Comment: @JánLalinský Nothing restricts the utility of Kirchhoff's laws to linear circuits.

Comment: @JánLalinský There's nothing fictitious about parasitic elements. When we intentionally concentrate displacement current in an object, we call the object a capacitor. Parasitic capacitors are the same thing, just unintentional and not so concentrated. As with intentional capacitors, their capacitance may be computed from geometry. This is not a "fitting enterprise". It's a special case of the finite element method.

Comment: Well finite element method is different. I meant introducing parasitic elements without justification in deeper theory than circuital equations, is a fitting enterprise, without justification. I agree that there may be a physics justification for parasitic elements in deeper theory involving $\mathbf D$.

Comment: @JánLalinský I don't know why you think it unjustified. There's nothing mathematically shaky here, but more importantly, it works. That's the justification a physical idea needs.

Comment: I meant not justified by the physical theory. It may be justified by its results, that's another kind of justification.

Comment: @JánLalinský It is fully justified by classical electrodynamics. But of course, that's mere mathematical justification, not physics.

Comment: @JánLalinský The distinction arises when we apply the two flavors of the continuity equation to a real circuit, as it appears OP is trying to do. One approach says the current flowing out of any closed surface is zero, the other says "it depends". There is no real distinction in the context of a lumped circuit graph (except what capacitor currents really represent): we have to assume KCL because it's a fundamental assumption of circuit theory. Yes, displacement currents provide rationalization of parasitic capacitances in a lumped circuit. [...]

Comment: @JánLalinský [...] An isolated spherical capacitor can be represented in a lumped circuit by a capacitor between the spherical conductor and "infinity" (ground). If we are not including displacement currents, we are forced to say no current actually flows through the region this capacitor represents (no charge flow takes place in air). Including displacement currents allows us to speak of actual current flow through the capacitor. In any case, the theory is unambiguous and whether we accept displacement currents as "real" in this context is merely a matter of interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

When there is a charge in a conductor, then the net supplied voltage will be the algebraic sum of the voltage source and the voltage because of the charge in the conductor. The net voltage source will be equal to the net voltage drop and is the [Kirchhoff’s Voltage Law](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-6/kirchhoffs-voltage-law-kvl/) (KVL).